# I need some help to get a .png image to show up with the opencv 2.4.3 library in netbeans

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

I received this error in my testing attempt of my template in java on netbeans in Ubuntu 12.04. What do I need to do from here based on the error information below the code. What is it saying that I should do to fix my problem.

Here is my code

```
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

    public class again {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
     Mat m=Highgui.imread("/root/image.png",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_OLOR);




      }
  }
```

run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Ljava/lang/String;I)J
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:296)
    at again.main(again.java:22)
Java Result: 1

UPDATE:**I changed the code and it said it compiled successfully but I still can't get it to show the image in a window. I also have another class thats suppose to be "interconnected" to show the picture but it doesn't.**

```
    public class again {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

}

     Mat m=Highgui.imread("/root/image.png",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    LoadImage loadImage= new LoadImage("/root/image.png",m);



}
```

**Here's the other class**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class LoadImage extends JFrame {
         public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
       public LoadImage(String imgStr,Mat m)
  {
       Highgui.imwrite(imgStr,m);
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("My GUI");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     frame.setResizable(true);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      // Inserts the image icon
      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgStr);
      frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth()+10,image.getIconHeight()+35);

     // Draw the Image data into the BufferedImage
     JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" ", image, JLabel.CENTER);
     frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

         frame.validate();
         frame.setVisible(true);}



    }
```

**Sorry I couldn't get it to fit right, but I can't find out what version of java I am using or even worse I might not have java installed**

```
    root@ubuntu:/# sudo java –version
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: –version
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    Could not find the main class: –version. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to be to use the package of OpenCV provided by PatternDiscussing and use a maven project.

As described on their GitHub project page:
https://github.com/patternconsulting/opencv

I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9-7</version>
    </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file and this code before the main.

```
static {
    nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();
}
```

For an Ant project, which are just called Java Projects in Netbeans:

Download the jar itself from: 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/nu/pattern/opencv/2.4.9-7/opencv-2.4.9-7.jar

Right-click Libraries under your project in the projects window, choose Add Jar/Folder, select the downloaded jar.

You also need to extract all the files from it with:

jar -xf ~/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9-7.jar

Instead of using nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(); just call System.load() on the correct version of the shared library for your platform.

eg.

```
static {
    System.load("/home/shackle/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_32/libopencv_java249.so");
}
```

With either of those changes it worked for me.

You will need a modern version of the JDK.

To get the latest netbeans and the JDK on any platform: 
Use the "Netbeans with JDK8" here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

To setup ubuntu repositories to pull in JDK 8.
Follow the instructions here:
http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/

Once that is done you may need to add that JDK as a platform and update the project settings to use the later JDK.
To add a platform:
Goto Tools-> Java Platforms menu in Netbeans and click the "Add Platform" button.

To update the project settings:
Select your project, right-click for properties, select libraries and select a different platform in the drop-down box labelled Java Platform.

Comment: I ran into problems trying to get the library to install and I needed to download libraries for Ubuntu such as the junit library but I tried to follow the help on ubuntufourms from previous answers; but it didn't work.

Comment: Thats strange maven should install the correct version of junit if/when its necessary. Netbeans already comes with junit versions 3.8.2 and 4.10 that was fine for my  ant based project. Besides junit is only used in automated unit testing and shouldn't be required building or running this application. Are you using the pattern consulting package?

Comment: I tried to make my own package to load and copied the OpenCV.java from the source I downloaded from the github. I found out I don't have the import java.nio.file.*; capabilities in netbeans on Ubuntu. I tried to search all over google; but I couldn't find the library for netbeans on linux. Can you help me from here.

Comment: What is the pattern consulting package? I did try to read the readmes and the site on github; but I didn't read it throughly because I am in a hurry.

Comment: The pattern consulting package is the project/jar file I included links to in my answer. It is prebuilt so you won't need the OpenCV source. Not having java.nio.file.* indicates you are using a really old version of the JDK. I will add instructions on how to get the latest version.

Comment: I was able to get the code nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared(); to not show up underlined in red by copying the OpenCV.java class into a package by the name of nu.pattern. I am trying to circumvent the problem I am encountering of trying to compile the opencv-stable I downloaded. Also, it says no such file exists or no import exists for "import java.nio.file.*;

Comment: Which version of java and netbeans are you using?

Comment: Okay I got it to work by following your instructions. Netbeans does say that it is compile successfully in green. But, it isn't displaying the image/picture I want in a window. Which is why I am using opencv and jframe. It isn't showing up in a window.

Comment: Strangely it says errors like this. root@ubuntu:/# sudo java –version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: –version
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –version
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 .......

Comment: Can you use the edit link directly directly under your original question so you can paste the entire error and format it so is readable.

Comment: I donwloaded the linux version. I come back later to follow the instructions